# typeof typeof x returns string and not object since type of null is object

Tags: javascript

I am new to `js`, trying to learn `js`, can you guys tell me why `typeof typeof x` returns `string`, providing code snippet below, if i understand this simple concept it will help me more:

```
var x=null;
console.log(typeof typeof x);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`typeof x` returns a string representation of the type of `x`. So, naturally, `typeof typeof x` is string.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

> The typeof operator returns a **string** indicating the type of the unevaluated operand.

If you want it to return "object" you need to change it to just one 'typeof'

```
var x=null;
console.log(typeof x);
```

Comment: in other words...using `typeof typeof variable` makes no sense

Comment: @jakeehoffmann so are you saying typeof typeof x is an unevaluated operand ??

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, so no. Use `typeof` on anything you like. The result will be a string which reads the type of whatever you put in it. Thus `typeof (typeof anything)` is equivalent to `typeof "somestring"` which is, of course, "string".

Answer (score 1):

Check this simple example, it will clear your doubt:

```js
var a = null;

console.log(typeof a, typeof a === 'object')

var b = function (){};

console.log(typeof b, typeof b === 'function')

var c = "";

console.log(typeof c, typeof c === 'string')
```

**Reason**: `typeof` returns a string, of the type of the value you provided, When you check the value returned by `typeof`, it will be in string form, like:

```
'object', 'function', 'string' etc.
```

And you are checking the `typeof "object"`, that's why it returned `string`.

Comment: type of object should be object right but why its returning string...can you use my example in the answer...its confusing :(

Comment: `typeof object` will be `object` but `typeof "object"` will be `string` just notice the `""` around the object, that's the difference. When you use `typeof obeject` it will `return "object"` again you are using `typeof` on that, it will be like `typeof "object"`, that's why it returned `string` :)

Comment: how come it will go inside "" since we are not giving quotes right??

Comment: i will be returned by `typeof` in that format, check the comparison i used in above example, that comparison returned true because `typeof` is returning either `'function' or 'string' or 'object' etc` :)

Answer (score 0):

typeof operator to find the data type of a JavaScript variable
// This stands since the beginning of JavaScript
typeof null === 'object';

```
var x=null;
var x=(typeof x);
it returns "object";
var y=typeof "object";
it returns string
so 
console.log(typeof typeof x);
show string
```